# Jquery tabs(horizontal) with in Accordion?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to have multiple tabs(horizontal) with in single collapsible Accordion??
IF yes then please give me some live example (link)...

Comment: Stack Overflow is to help with problems you are having, not to act as a Google intermediary. Please read the FAQ regarding the kind of questions you should ask here.

Comment: I serached over google and found multiple accordion inside single tab...but i need opposite of it..i.e multiple tabs inside single accordion(and i found nothing related to this on google that is why i am asking here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? It's a jquery plugin.
http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/